# I want to insert a image in a cell which is the part of UITableView(grouped) with the coordination(image) in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to insert a image in a cell which is the part of UITableView(grouped) with the coordination(image) in iphone ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `UITableViewCell`'s `imageView` property to set an image.

```
myCell.imageView.image = myImage;
```